Add Folder in shared google drive to iPad files program
I have read access to a folder on someone else's Google drive.  I want to create a shortcut to that folder in the files app on my iPad.  The directions from Google include functions that do not exist on iOS 18.
What can I do to create that shortcut.  I now have to use a bookmark in Chrome to get to the folder, then download the files I want, to then open them in a new application (forScore).
Suggestions?
